# scrapw from popup windows

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, popup

Suppose in a web page I pressed a button to open a popup window.

in this popup window some tabs are presented.

How can I code so that be able to scrape all content in the tabs in the popup window?

I use following codes but that does not work.

can you provide any solution:

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'extractLinks') {
    //const pdfLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]')).map((a) => a.href);
    //  const pdfLinks = Array.from(document.getElementById('li_dosya_evrak_bilgileri').querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]')).map((a) => a.href);
    const pdfLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal-content #li_dosya_evrak_bilgileri a[href$=".pdf"]')).map((a) => a.href);

    sendResponse({
      links: pdfLinks
    });
  }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Extension Installed');
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'getLinks') {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    }, (tabs) => {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
        action: 'extractLinks'
      }, (response) => {
        sendResponse(response);
      });
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('extractLinks').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'getLinks'
  }, (response) => {
    const linkList = document.getElementById('linkList');
    linkList.innerHTML = '';
    response.links.forEach((link) => {
      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.textContent = link;
      linkList.appendChild(listItem);
      chrome.downloads.download({
        url: link,
        filename: 'your_custom_filename.pdf'
      });

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id="extractLinks">Extract Links</button>
  <ul id="linkList"></ul>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It depends on whether the opened window has an identifiable URL. If it does you can get the new tabs via chrome.tabs.query.